# Get gitlab file archive for most recent release

Tags: gitlab

This will let me get an archive from a repo:

`GET /projects/:id/repository/archive.tar.gz`

Is there any way to pass a parameter such that I get an archive for the latest release rather than just the HEAD?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the tags of repository using the following API:

```
GET /projects/:id/repository/tags
```

As the docs describe https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/tags.html#list-project-repository-tags

You get a list of repository tags from a project, sorted by update date and time in descending order

In combination with the archive API

```
GET /projects/:id/repository/archive[.format]
```

We can have the latest release with the following one-liner:

```
curl  --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <private token>" https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/<project id>/repository/archive.tar.gz?sha=$(curl -s --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <private token>" "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/<project id>/repository/tags" | jq '.[0].commit.id' | sed 's/^"\(.*\)"$/\1/') -o /path/to/file
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but I was hoping for a 1-liner where I didn't have to query the repo for the sha associated with the most recent tag.

Comment: Excume me I misunderstood, is the update what you seek?